# Importerror: no module named 'Adafruit_DHT'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

Okay, so I normally use PuTTY to write and run programs on my RiPi3. I have ran this program through PuTTY just fine, but when I try to run it ON the Pi through Thonny Python or Python 3, the program will not run.

```
ImportError: No module named 'Adafruit_DHT'
```

I am trying to run this program on my Pi because I am using Tkinter and I cannot run Tkinter through PuTTY to bring up the GUI as far as I know.

I would just run the program on my PC, but I am integrating the DHT22 temperature sensor into the program, so I need the Pi.

I have gone through and installed all the newest updates and packages.

I'll remind you that this program (without Tkinter) works on PuTTY.

What is the issue here??

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thonny uses it's own copy of python, so things you install to the system python will not be available in thonny. You will have to use the terminal (Ctrl-Alt-T), which will give you the same interface as Putty.

BTW, you *can* use tkinter over ssh. You just have to use this command first:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

That tells tkinter to draw on the screen instead of trying to draw in the putty window.